# Creating a pop up menu for a Tkinter Treeview in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Is it possible to have a tkinter treeview located in a child window that contains a popup menu when an item in the treeview is clicked. At the moment the menu is displayed on a right click and is directed to the appropriate function, however I have been unable to then identify the item selected in the treeview.

Is there a way to identify the row that has been selected in the treeview after the menu has been used?

Thanks in advance

```
class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    button = ttk.Button(self, text="Treeview", command= self.ChildWindow)
    button.pack()


def ChildWindow(self):

    #Create menu
    popup = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
    popup.add_command(label="Next", command=self.selection)
    popup.add_separator()

    def do_popup(event):
        # display the popup menu
        try:
            popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
        finally:
            # make sure to release the grab (Tk 8.0a1 only)
            popup.grab_release()

    #Create Treeview
    win2 = Toplevel()
    new_element_header=['1st']
    treeScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(win2)
    treeScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(win2,columns=new_element_header, show="headings")
    self.tree.heading("1st", text="1st")
    self.tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 1", values=("1A"))
    self.tree.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

    self.tree.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)

    win2.minsize(600,30)

def selection(self, event):
    selection = self.tree.set(self.tree.identify_row(event.y))
    print selection
```

Comment: I had tried this before. I don't remember well but I am sure I designed a menu and used the `menu.post()` function. Also there is a function in treeview, something like `tree.identify(x, y)` which can be used to find if the user clicked spot is a cell, heading, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I've tried to update your original code to be the following and it now works. See also this question: [how to pass values to popup command on right click in python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464386/how-to-pass-values-to-popup-command-on-right-click-in-python-tkinter])

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.root = parent;
        self.button = tk.Button(parent, text="Treeview", command=self.ChildWindow)
        self.button.pack()


    def ChildWindow(self):

        #Create menu
        self.popup = tk.Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
        self.popup.add_command(label="Next", command=self.selection)
        self.popup.add_separator()

        def do_popup(event):
            # display the popup menu
            try:
                self.popup.selection = self.tree.set(self.tree.identify_row(event.y))
                self.popup.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
            finally:
                # make sure to release the grab (Tk 8.0a1 only)
                self.popup.grab_release()

        #Create Treeview
        win2 = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        new_element_header=['1st']
        treeScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(win2)
        treeScroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(win2, columns=new_element_header, show="headings")
        self.tree.heading("1st", text="1st")
        self.tree.insert("" ,  0, text="Line 1", values=("1A"))
        self.tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.tree.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)

        win2.minsize(600,30)

    def selection(self):
        print self.popup.selection

root = tk.Tk()

Page(root, None)

root.mainloop()

def main():
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```